# Connect to database PostSQL using ssh tunnel in R

Tags: r, postgresql, ssl, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Objective is to connect **R** to **PostgreSQL** using an SSH tunnel.

Just had unsuccessful tries with libraries `RPostgreSQL` and `DBI`. I'm not finding a way to pass along SSH tunneling parameters (proxy host, proxy user, and private key).

I wonder if there's a way to somehow specify those SSH parameters along in db query string? Maybe another way out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212693/make-an-ssh-tunnel-to-another-computer-via-r-to-access-postgresql-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code sample that I've used:

First, setup an ssh tunnel - this would be for an AWS EC2 instance:

```
ssh -i 'YOURKEY.pem' -N -L 1234:YOURDATABASEHOST:5432 YOURUSER@YOURAWSINSTANCE
```

Then in R:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

conn <- dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), dbname = 'MYREMOTEDBNAME', host = '127.0.0.1', port = 1234, password = 'MYREMOTEPASSWORD', user = 'MYREMOTEUSER')
```

As you can see, the key is to setup a tunnel between a remote instance of some kind and the remote database.  Then you use this locally hosted tunnel (hence, 127.0.0.1 as your host) and the specified port (1234 in this case).