# How to connect to a Postgres database with a ssh tunnel with R?

Tags: r, postgresql, pgadmin-4, rpostgresql

at work we have a database to which the following series of commands connected me from R.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL") 

con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = drv,
  host = "rocket.cluster-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user = " webapp",
  password = "1234",
  dbname = "rocket"
)
```

I have tried to replicate the following parameters in R. But I have not been successful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKc7k.png)

Currently I connect from pgAdmin but I am interested in connecting in R

Comment: try the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212693/make-an-ssh-tunnel-to-another-computer-via-r-to-access-postgresql-table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an SSH tunnel to another computer via R to access postgreSQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212693/make-an-ssh-tunnel-to-another-computer-via-r-to-access-postgresql-table)