# Why is Mariadb behaving differently when access it via PuTTY or via R?

Tags: r, ssh, mariadb, putty

Rephrasing a previous question. I am trying to understand why I can get access to Mariadb via SSH over PuTTY but not over R. I'm using Windows 11 v. 22H2; server is hosted with cpanel.

Opening the connection over PuTTY, I can log in Mariadb using

```
mysql -u USER -p;
```

And from there I can `show databases;` and perform other SQL queries.

However, from R, after connecting via SSH, I cannot open a connection to Mariadb. In R, this fails:

```
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                            host='localhost',
                            user='USER',
                            password='PW')
```

With either "cannot connect to server" or "host is not allowed to connect  to this MariaDB server)

> **NOTE:** I'm working on contacting the right ppl in order to add a user as
> described in
> [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)
> ... but I don't even understand ***WHY*** I need to do it since it works
> in PuTTY, using the exact same credentials.

I also tried to connect using

```
ssh_exec_wait(ssh_connection, command = 'mysql -u USER -p' )
```

worst case scenario R crashes; best case scenario the console prompts for a password but I cannot figure how to input it (yes, I tried typing it in the console an pressing Enter. Doesn't do anything.) I receive messages that R is responding to OpenSSH's keepalive.

The whole message:

```
channel_open: Creating a channel 43 with 64000 window and 32768 max packet
ssh_packet_global_request: Received SSH_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST packet
ssh_packet_global_request: UNKNOWN SSH_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST hostkeys-00@openssh.com, want_reply = 0
ssh_packet_global_request: Invalid SSH_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST packet
ssh_packet_ignore_callback: Received SSH_MSG_DEBUG packet
ssh_packet_channel_open_conf: Received a CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION for channel 43:0
ssh_packet_channel_open_conf: Remote window : 0, maxpacket : 32768
channel_rcv_change_window: Adding 2097152 bytes to channel (43:0) (from 0 bytes)
channel_request: Channel request exec success
grow_window: growing window (channel 43:0) to 1280000 bytes
Enter password: channel_rcv_request: Responding to Openssh's keepalive
```

So, I am trying to learn and understand why I can connect with PuTTY, but not R?

Comment: What does `select user();` return when you login via the MySQL client?

Comment: If you use putty via ssh, then the connection is made as if the client was on the same server your mariadb. When you connect from R, then you connect remotely.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not you are first connecting to the server using SSH and then running R? Your first comment "from R, after connecting via SSH" suggests that you are but then `ssh_exec_wait(ssh_connection, command = 'mysql -u USER -p' )` suggests that you are not.

Comment: @neilfws I tried pretty much all variation: SSH first, then R; SSH first +SSH in R; SSH in R only. always the same result.

Comment: @neilfws select user(); in MYSQL client returns the username I'm using (USER@localhost)

Comment: OK: so we know that the hostname is the expected 'localhost'. If you cannot connect from R **on the machine where the database lives** _i.e._ **SSH first then run R**, using the same user, password and hostname, then something else is different. What does `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';` return in the MySQL client?

Comment: @neilfws 3306 (as expected). I tried specifying the port in my R connection - to no avail. `mysqlconnection = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), host='localhost', user='USER', password='PW', port=3306)` gives the same "cannot connect to localhost" error

Comment: OK, I don't think we can help more without knowing how the server is set up. Hopefully those "right ppl" can.

Comment: @neilfws still nice to know I didn't miss something obvious!

Comment: The *"after connecting via SSH"* is unclear. My wild guess is that you establish an SSH connection in a R and then you expect that `localhost` will magically become the remote machine. It won't. If my guess is correct, you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38212693/850848 – If not, we need [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you're db server is listenning you'r R client ? mysql native client is probably rputed to a local socket when R is not.

Comment: no idea how to check that. Any pointers?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/

Comment: Or in R [unix.socket](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RMySQL/versions/0.10.25/topics/dbConnect,MySQLDriver-method). Look at `\s` on the `mysql` client when connected to see how it connected.